# Передача данных из Swing в другой класс

Tags: gui, java, swing

Всем привет!
Возник такой вопрос.
Если я делаю Swing-приложение, там отрисовываю textField, в него ввожу данные, то как получить эти данные в другом классе?
Ведь получается, что у нас GUI в одном Thread-е (в event dispathc thread), а нужный класс - в другом.
И как передавать данные туда, в GUI из класса?

Comment: создай объект своего класса в конструкторе JFrame.

Comment: @aarexer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я уже точно не помню, но синхронизоваться можно через `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` или `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`. Покопай в эту сторону, это точно то, что тебе нужно. К сожалению, дословно сейчас код не приведу, давненько не писал.

Answer (score 0):

Объявление JTextField сделай статическим полем, и получай оттуда данные методом <поленэйм>.getText(); когда хочешь